# WPF: How to loop through ContextMenu to rearrange the items in it or add a menuitem as a subitem to Menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a ContextMenu with the following items 
**My current Contextmenu**
[image: My current Contextmenu]

However I want it in this format **My requirement**
[image]

This is how far I have got

```
 foreach (var menuItem in oMenuItemList)
 {
      var cContextMenuItem = menuItem as MenuItem;
      if (cContextMenuItem != null)
      {
          _oContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
          if (cContextMenuItem.Header.ToString() == "1.1")
          {
               MenuItem newMenuItem2 = new MenuItem();
               MenuItem newExistMenuItem = (MenuItem)this._oContextMenu.Items[0];

               newExistMenuItem.Items.Add(newMenuItem2);

               _oContextMenu.Items.Add(newExistMenuItem);
            }
        }
   }
 _oContextMenu.ItemsSource = oMenuItemList;
```

Updated code

```
IEnumerable oMenuItemList = null;
oMenuItemList = GetContextMenuItems(sMenuItems);

//the function
private List<object> GetContextMenuItems(string sMenuItems)
{
 //returns the list
}

_oContextMenu.ItemsSource = oMenuItemList;
```

After this Im trying to manipulate the _oContextMenu.

Comment: Why are you checking if the item has the Header "Program"?

Comment: I'm sorry corrected to 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example for your exact images:

Xaml:

```
<ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_OnOpened">
    <MenuItem Header="1.0" />
    <MenuItem Header="1.1" />
    <MenuItem Header="1.2" />
    <MenuItem Header="2.0" />
    <MenuItem Header="3.0" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void ContextMenu_OnOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)sender;

    var firstItem = (MenuItem)contextMenu.Items[0];

    // Must create new array of existing menu items
    // to be able to edit existing context menu during loop enumeration.
    var allItems = contextMenu.Items.Cast<MenuItem>().ToArray();

    foreach (var item in allItems)
    {
        if (item.Header.ToString() == "1.1" || item.Header.ToString() == "1.2")
        {
            // Add menu item with the same header into another item as sub-item
            firstItem.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = item.Header });

            // Remove item from root level.
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I used conditions for specific headers text ("1.1" and "1.2") and put items inside first menu item, but you can implement any logic you need in your particular program.

`Opened` event triggers every time context menu opened, so you can make any dynamic changes that required in current moment of time.

### Update1

Below is example when `ItemsSource` binding involved. Advantage is that you can interact just with `MenuItemsCollection` and don't worry about `ContextMenu` object itself, its visual items and other details.

Xaml:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_OnOpened" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsCollection}" />
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItemsCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>
{
    new MenuItem { Header = "1.0" },
    new MenuItem { Header = "1.1" },
    new MenuItem { Header = "1.2" },
    new MenuItem { Header = "2.0" },
    new MenuItem { Header = "3.0" },
};

private void ContextMenu_OnOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var firstItem = this.MenuItemsCollection[0];

    var allItems = this.MenuItemsCollection.ToArray();

    foreach (var item in allItems)
    {
        if (item.Header.ToString() == "1.1" || item.Header.ToString() == "1.2")
        {
            firstItem.Items.Add(item);
            this.MenuItemsCollection.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update2

If you want assign new items list every time directly to `ContextMenu` element:

```
private void ContextMenu_OnOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // var actualItems = GetListOfItemsAnyWayYouNeed();
    var actualItems = new List<MenuItem>
    {
        new MenuItem {
            Header = "1.0",
            Items =
            {
                new MenuItem { Header = "1.1" },
                new MenuItem { Header = "1.2" } }
            },
        new MenuItem { Header = "2.0" },
        new MenuItem { Header = "3.0" },
    };

    _oContextMenu.ItemsSource = actualItems;
}
```

### Conclusion

After setting value to `ItemsSource`, you can not more manipulate the `_oContextMenu`, at least its `Items` property - you will get error from your first comment. That means you can't do things like in my original answer, because you assign directly to `ItemsSource`.

You try to set `oMenuItemList`directly to `_oContextMenu.ItemsSource`(similar to things shown in Update2), but after that you can't manipulate `_oContextMenu.Items`. You can only manipulate your `oMenuItemList` (if you save it in global variable), but it will not change actual menu content because your list is not `ObservableCollection`.

If you still want to do all things in code, try this:

```
ObservableCollection<object> oMenuItemList { get; set; }

...

oMenuItemList = GetContextMenuItems(sMenuItems);

//the function
private ObservableCollection<object> GetContextMenuItems(string sMenuItems)
{
    //returns the ObservableCollection
}

_oContextMenu.ItemsSource = oMenuItemList;
```

And any changes you will make in `oMenuItemList` **(but not in `_oContextMenu.Items`)** will applied in actual context menu.

But anyway the best approach is still to do like described in Update1.

Comment: Hi Sam,  the code fails at contextMenu.Items.Remove(item); saying "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead"

Comment: @user6384353 I guess you provide menu items through `ItemsSource` binding. Can you provide your `ContextMenu` xaml declaration?

Comment: @user6384353 I think I understand what are you trying to do, see my conclusion in answer.